# Understanding Dao-pattern, can it be used for retrieving data from cache?

Tags: java, caching, dao

I read about DAO-pattern in [the official documentation](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/dataaccessobject-138824.html) and it's not quite clear if it can be used for retrieving data from cache?

Formally speaking, `DAO` is an additional abstraction layer between clients and mechanism the data is being retrieved from somewhere. So, if data resides in cache, I suppose we might as well call the DAO something like

```
public interface UserDao {
    //CRUD operations
}

public class UpdatableCachedUserDaoImpl implements UserDao {
     //Normal dao
     private final UserDao userDao;
     private volatile List<User> cache;

    //Delegates CRUD operation to cache
    //Updates the cache through ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor
    //using the Normal Dao
}
```

But is it correct to place such cache-related logic in DAO? Or DAO is intended to work precisely with data-source or something else persistent storage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Data Access Object` pattern doesn't address what the data is or where it's being accessed. Whether it makes sense to access a cache from a `DAO` depends a lot on the other architecture of the system.

Comment: Can't imagine how it may depend on the architecture. What could potentially prevent me from puttin such logic in DAO? Maybe cahe-updating is not strictly fit for DAO

Comment: Well, for example do you want the DAO to know that you have a cache? Or do you want the DAO to think it's accessing a database, but there's an invisible cache in between?

Comment: Particularly for UpdatableCachedUserDaoImpl, yes, I want to be "cahce-awared". As implies from the class name...

Comment: I'm not talking about your situation here. You seem to be hacking together your architecture anyway.

Comment: So, you talked about a general contract we have in our project. I mean, whether it's acceptable to have a dao to know about cache. Or what...?

Comment: I'm talking about the DAO pattern, and told you that it doesn't concern itself with that. Whether it's "correct" for a DAO to know about a cache is debatable. It introduces a dependency after all.